# second action not working onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick

i want a `div` to change to green color when I click on a `checkbox`, then again when I click the checkbox the green color should be removed. When I add `$('div.formfld').removeClass('green');` the action of adding the green color also disappears.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".clicker").click(function(){
                $('div.formfld').addClass('green');
                $('div.formfld').removeClass('green'); 
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .formfld{ padding:5px; }
        .grey{ background-color:#CCCCCC; }
        .green{ background-color:#006600; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="formfld grey" id="frm">
        <input type="checkbox" class="clicker" /> 
        Name
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are both adding, then removing the class for every click. Use `toggleClass` instead. Also, use the `change` event on the element to ensure access for users who cannot use a mouse:

```
$(".clicker").change(function(){
    $('div.formfld').toggleClass('green');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nA3v8/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch the class

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".clicker").click(function () {
        $('div.formfld').toggleClass('green');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uzBq2/)

Answer (score 3):

Try [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('div.formfld').toggleClass('green');
```